# How does the computational complexity of problems depend on the model specifics of a register machine?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

On wikipedia page of register machines it says that all register machines defined appropriately are equivalent to Turing machines but that

> Computational speed is very dependent on the model specifics.

Does this mean that when we say a problem has complexity $O(n^2)$ or is a polynomial time problem, or something like that, this is assuming some specific model of computation? If so, how general is the statement that a problem is in $P$ or in $NP$ or anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

The basic definitions of computational complexity are normally phrased in terms of plain Turing Machines, so one has to be careful about transferring results to different models. Naturally, if you can perform look-ups faster, any program that requires that functionality will also be faster (at least for that part).

However if the other model is not to extreme, then the gap in the precise running times falls below our normal threshold of caring. That is, most models of fairly general interest are polynomially equivalent to Turing Machines, so even though a register machine is in some sense faster than a Turing Machine, it's not so much faster that it breaks the definitions - it only speeds things up by a polynomial factor (i.e. an $O(n^{a})$ algorithm will only go down to a $O(n^{b})$ algorithm with $b \leq a$).

You can of course define models that are significantly faster than a Turing Machine (for a trivial example, a Turing Machine that can solve $\mathsf{Clique}$ in a single step), at this point, you can't feasibly replace "Turing Machine" in the definition of $\mathsf{P}$ or $\mathsf{NP}$ with the new model without changing things significantly (but models like this do have other uses).

Comment: "without changing things significantly". Does that mean that we cannot make a computer based on classical physics that has a different opinion than Turing Machines about whether something falls in $P$ or in $NP$?

Comment: @Programmer2134 actually, if we take only classical physics, you could theoretically make something more powerful than a Turing Machine - there's a bizarre arrangement of stars that can compute the halting problem by exploiting the lack of universal speed limit. Of course we don't live in a classical physics world, and we do have $c$. It's possible that substituting Quantum TM for TM gives something different (it seems that way at the moment), but you introduce error then, so it's a different proposition to other substitutions, of course a QTM doesn't make more things computable, it just...

Comment: ... changes what might be efficiently computable.

Comment: What you said about classical physics is bizarre, and Interesting. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @Programmer2134 This is not the one I was  thinking of particularly, but Section 2.2 of https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e091/a7918f4d8a39a4ac5044a237daf7796455a0.pdf is a good start.

Comment: @Programmer2134 You may also find some of this interesting: http://www2.cs.uni-paderborn.de/cs/ag-madh/WWW/ziegler/DFG/2009_Ziegler_AMC.pdf